# Recovering through seed phrase; Old MetaMask (mnemonics password) is still working to access the wallet?

Tags: metamask, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When I do recovering my wallet using seed phrase, So on creating a new password and all doing fine.
But when I try to unlock the wallet with old password; It's working!!
Is there any approach to invalidate old password?

Comment: That seems to be a bug in Metamask. Did you try contacting their support?

Comment: @Ismael I didn't, I reproduce this by copying MetaMask extension's chrome Local Storage files before changing the password, When I do recovering by seed phrase either private key and creating a new password. then I copy old local storage files into their place. I try to unlock the wallet with old password and it open the same wallet.

Comment: @Ismael I know that the old mnemonics are encrypted with the old password, But I don't understand how exact this extension work and open the same wallet with all it's functionality.

Comment: Metamask is open source so you should be able to read the code and study what they are doing. It is likely the file you are copying contains the mnemonic encrypted with the password. Obviously the old copy will be encrypted by the old password.